# Find a polynomial that satisfy the given given conditions.... Zeros - 1,1,2^1/2 integer coefficient and constant term 6...

Tags: rational-functions

Find a polynomial that satisfy the given given conditions.... Zeros - 1,1,2^1/2 integer coefficient and constant term 6... My question is how do I make them integers... I tried multiplying by square root 2 but I also get square... Any hint would be helpful
Thank you

Comment: Are the zeros meant to be $-1,1,\sqrt2$ or $1,1,\sqrt2$?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Start with $(x-1)^2(x^2-2)$.

Comment: I assume the OP meant zeros to be $1$ (twice) and $\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$3(x^2-2)(x^2-1).$$
.

Comment: @lhf $3(-2)(-1)=6$, so $3$ is fine.